# Impedance Expression for a Transmission Line

Tags: impedance, transmission-line, homework

I'm studying transmission line theory and this is the expression I derived for the input impedance for a lossless transmission line:

$$
Z(\omega) = Z_{\inf} \frac{1+e^{i\frac{\pi\omega}{\omega_{0}}}}{1-e^{i\frac{\pi\omega}{\omega_{0}}}}
$$

where 
$$
Z_{\inf}=\sqrt{L/C}
$$
is the wave impedance and 
$$
\omega_0=\frac{\pi/2}{\sqrt{LC}}
$$
is the quarter-wavelength resonance frequency.

Now, I found this other expression very similar to mine but I'm not able to figure out if they are the same or not and eventually which one is correct

$$
Z(\omega) = Z_{\inf} \frac{e^{i\frac{\pi\omega}{\omega_{0}}}-1}{e^{i\frac{\pi\omega}{\omega_{0}}}+1}
$$

Comment: The difference is a - sign, maybe you omitted it in your calculations?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: if you compare my expression with what you can find in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) for example, the signs seem correct. The point is that also the other reference is trustworthy...

Comment: I mixed the signs, the first is actually the second, inverted. Could it be that, maybe, the book was referring to the attenuation factor, instead of impedance?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen: no, it refers to the impedance. I would send you the .pdf of that page, if there would be a way. The thing is that in the reference, all the conclusions are derived starting from this expression, so I need to be sure if it's correct or not.